# Change font colour based on date result

Tags: php, html

Im trying to change my font within a table based on the date return field.

I've got a table that displays all entries that should be returned today using:

```
 $my_query="select * from items WHERE date_return = CURDATE()";
 $result= mysqli_query($connection, $my_query);
```

I want to know implement this sort of thing on my table that displays all entries and change the font colour based on a specific result.

```
 if ($returned == 'Yes'){ 
        $table.= '<td><div style="color: green;">'.$itemid.'</div>';
    } else if ($date_return == "CURDATE()") {
        $table.= '<td><div style="color: red;">'.$itemid.'</div>';
    } else{
        $table.= '<td><div style="color: blue;">'.$itemid.'</div>';
    } //end if
```

However the records that have a date_return same as todays date aren't displaying in red, skips straight through to blue.

Am I missing something?

Comment: instead of `"CURDATE()"` in second if, use PHP's [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format. It is dependent on what your date format in DB is. If your DB has `2016-12-13` it should be `date("Y-m-d")` then. `CURDATE()` is an SQL function, it won't work with PHP.

Comment: @Thamilan ah that would be why, tested this and it is working as I wanted,  if you would like, write up an answer for this and I shall mark is as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURDATE()` in second if is an SQL function. It won't work with PHP. Instead, use PHP's date format. It is dependent on what your [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) format in DB is.

If your DB has `2016-12-13` it should be `date("Y-m-d")` then.